# Не обрабатывается кнопка - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не обрабатывается кнопка при ее нажатии, хотя скрипт к кнопке подключен, метод вызывается, но  через breakpoint приложение не останавливает при нажатии на кнопку, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А как вы определили, что метод вызывается? По идее если брейкпоинт, находящийся в этом методе, не сработал, то значит метод не был вызван.

Comment: Слишком мало информации, очень бы помог хотя бы скрин самого скрипта